# Applying Twitter API using example but return Null

Tags: php, twitter

I am using twitter-api-php-master to search keywords through twitter but got Null return. Really  not sure why it is like that.

My code is like:

```
<?php

#### Include the class file ####

    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

#### Set access tokens ####

    $settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "[something]",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "[something]",
    'consumer_key' => "[something]",
    'consumer_secret' => "[something]"
    );


$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$getfield = '?q=test&geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi&count=100';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response =  $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                 ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->performRequest();
var_dump(json_decode($response));
?>
```

I pretty much copy this from example from https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/wiki/Twitter-API-PHP-Wiki. But the result is just Null. Someone knows what is the problem?